# SvelteKit - hotreload for .ts and .js not working

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

After installing SvelteKit [via this guide](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs) and write some code i have problem: hot reload works for .svelte and .html, but not works for .ts and .js files. After editing .ts or .js i need restart dev server for changes. How fix it?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I had this problem while starting out with SvelteKit too.
Restarting my IDE fixed it for me. If that doesn't work try restarting your PC, as that has also worked for a friend of mine.